# Screen Tearing in VLC

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player

In Ubuntu with a GeForce 26 w/ the official nVidia driver, there is tearing when playing a video in fullscreen. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Nvidia Settings and look for a an option called "Sync(hronize) every frame", this should prevent tearing.